# SetParam - Username & Session

Tags: php, mysqli

Lets say I have a session named `$_SESSION['user']`

And now, I want to use SetParam to be able to print out the username on the site using `{username}` (without the php tags)

Should it be something like this maybe?

```
public $db; // Database variable(?)
public function Param() {
    $this->db->setParams('username', $_SESSION['user']);
}
```

I'm really new into this "function" or whatever it is, and I will be grateful if you could help me out a bit.

Comment: There's bind_param, never heard of setParam.

Comment: If you want to print username, then why are you using `$db` object?

Comment: Well, if you really new to all this function or whatever it is, you are supposed to educate yourself first. At least with basic things